# SVM model misclassifying training samples with big number of features

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm training SVM model on data:

- handwritten math symbols(represented as 46x46 images, concretely each symbol is represented as numpy.array, later reshaped into 1x2116 numpy.array),
- corresponding string label, e.g. '+'.

So I have 2116 features for one training sample. In total I have about 22000 training samples(one symbol can be represented many times in many different writting variants).

My trained SVM classifier is misclassifying test images(drew by myself in paint for now, keeping images 46x46 pixels, e.g. I've drawn '+', '\sum', 'i') with either '1' or '-' all the time.

I suspect that classifier is undefitting, thus it only outputs '1' or '-'. I was testing with many different values for gamma and C parameters. Here's a snippet of SVM training code:

```
# SVC.fit only accepts 2d train data array
# This transformation is necessary
nsamples, nx, ny = symbols.shape
symbols_dim2 = symbols.reshape((nsamples, nx * ny))

# For demo purposes I have choosen SVM Large Margin Classifier
# Initializing SVM classifier engine:
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=10, C=100)

# Fit data - symbols, labels - appropriately
classifier.fit(symbols_dim2, labels)
print 'Training has successfully completed ...'

print 'Saving classifier properties into a file ...'
joblib.dump(classifier, trained_classifiers_dir_prefix + 'svmClassifier.pkl')
```

This is the next code snipped from testing script:

```
# Load pre-saved classifier
classifier = joblib.load(data_dir_prefix + trained_classifier_dir_prefix + classifier_name)

print 'Classifier loaded - ready to use ...'

test_image = cv2.imread(test_data_dir_prefix + 'test3.jpg')
test_image = cv2.cvtColor(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

rows, cols = test_image.shape
test_image = test_image.reshape(1, rows * cols)

print('PREDICTION: ' + str(classifier.predict(test_image)))
```

Concretely, I've tried parameters values like: gamma = 10, C = 100; gamma = 0.1, C = 1; gamma = 0.001, C = 1.

- What direct problem might be causing such big misclassification?
- What SVM parameters are suitable for so many data features?
- Shall I try another classifier, like Neural Nets or Nearest Neighbors?

Note: sklearn.SVC.svm requires reshaping training samples from 46x46 to 1x2116 to keep symbols numpy.array dimension <= 2

Note: I use Python 2.7.10, scikit-learn 0.17.1

Note: The training data(math handwritten symbols) is originally obtained from CROHME dataset, converted(each symbol is extracted to 46x46 image). CROHME dataset: http://www.isical.ac.in/~crohme/CROHME_data.html

Here's the full code provided if you would like to test it on your own: https://github.com/XaiNano/CROHME_inkmls_extractor

I'm open for any suggestions. I can go for any another classifier. Thanks, for any help!

## UPDATE

Changing images from 46x46 to 26x26 obvoiusly helped, now it classified correctly 4/10 26x26 images, whereas with 46x46 it classified 1/10 test images. Moreover I changed classifier to nearest_centroid from sklearn.neighbors.

Comment: Image recongition is usually solved better with Neural Nets. You could try the Keras library for example which is easy to start with. Did you try any other algos e.g. GBM, random forests etc?

Comment: No, I didn't. I read that with SVM I can get up to 85% accuracy with my problem. I followed all the instructions for preparing data and choosing classifier from here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2013/JimenezNguyen_MathFormulas_final_paper.pdf. I'll definitely try Keras library.